# Container size is not the same as content when I use 'transform'

Tags: html, css

I have a div called 'imgSlide' with a image inside. I set the image width to 100% cause I need it to rescale with the navigator size. Now, the problem comes when I use the 'transform' property, I move up the image but then it leaves a space.

[Image to explain better my problem even more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqxKW.jpg)

I want to know how can I delete the space so the section below (yellow bar) can move up.

I would like a pure css solution but, if there is absolutely no way to make it possible with only css, I like to know how can I solve this in other ways.

PD: I don't want to use pixels or ems in container height because i need the container rescale when I shrink the navigator.

**Edit: I uploaded new image, I think it explains correctly what I'm looking for.**

```css
 

#slide{  
 transform: translateY(-20%); 
}
#imgSlide img{
 display:block;
 width:100%;
}
#content{  
 height:50px;
 background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <header>  
 </header>
 <section id="body"> 
  <section id="slide">
   <div id="imgSlide">
    <img src="https://images2.alphacoders.com/209/209140.jpg"/>
   </div>    
  </section>
  <section id="content">   
  </section>
 </section>
 <footer>
 </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: You should try to be more specific. What do you mean with "limits" here: `to make the limits of the container be the same of the content`? Should the image fill 100% of width? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry my english is not very good, but I have attached an image to explain  better my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you could wrap both the image and the content in a "container". Then apply the transform on this new container. That means you would transform the container containing BOTH the image and the content. I made an example fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/7ye5q8ke/2/

HTML:

```
<body>
   <div id="container">

      <section id="slide">
         <div id="imgSlide">
            <img src="https://images2.alphacoders.com/209/209140.jpg"/>
         </div>             
      </section>

      <section id="content">            
      </section>

   </div> <!-- Div Container END -->

</body>
```

CSS:

```
#slide{     

}
#imgSlide img{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
#content{       
    height:50px;
    background:yellow;
}

#container{
  transform: translateY(-20%);
}
```

---

Edit:

Noticed the fiddle was not working. Updated fiddle

---

Edit 2:

In your comment you're asking if it's semantically correct, it's not. If the section "content" actually is meant for image title, image description and so on, they should be inside the same section. The section attribute is meant for grouping together thematically related content. Meaning the section "content" should be inside the section "slide". Like so:

```
<section id="slide">
   <div id="imgSlide">
      ...
   </div>
   <div id="content">
   </div>
</section> <!-- Section slide ends -->
```

Now both the image content and the image are in the same section. Should be semantically correct. Check out this link http://oli.jp/2009/html5-structure1/

Comment: It's a partial solution, but I have two problems with it. First, it keeps the white space at the end of the div(the container), and second (and this is more a question than a statement), this would not be semantically right?, since the slider section should be only the slider, and the other sections should be in other section tags.

I would like to know if there is any way to delete the white space when I use "transform: translateY(-20%)" so the rest of the content of the website move up.

I just uploaded a new image to explain better my problem.

Comment: Updated my answer now. The fiddle was not working, but it's updated now  to suit your problems / questions. Read more about sections in the link I posted. Maybe it helps you at least understand the semantic question. ;)

Comment: Thanks for comment chrisv! The thing is the "content" section is not for the image title, I'm planning put a carousel with images inside of it, and that's why I think this section(content) should be outside of "slide" section. Back to my problem, as I said, even when I use this wrapper div, the white space between "content" and "slide" disappears, but reappears at the end of the wrapper